# Formatting the dates to desired format return invalid dates in python. How to control it?

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I have a list of dates like:

```
['2013-04-06', '06/04/2013', '04/06/2013', 'Apr 06 2013']
```

I have used `datetime.strftime()` for converting the dates like `('%d/%m/%Y')`, but when it converts the same dates with different formats like:

```
dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy
'06/04/2013' and '04/06/2013'
```

It returns the date as it is...
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not with 100 % reliability. If your date formats are this hopelessly mixed, you will never be able to tell if `04/06/2013` is supposed to be April 6th or June 4th.

Your only chance is to take the more common variant and try that first. If that throws an error or returns an implausible date (like one in the future, if those are not permitted), try the next one.

You might also want to look into [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). It does its best to parse a date in any given format.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric dates can be ambiguous. There are acouple of solutions;

- Use an abbreviated name for the month; both "apr 06 2013" or "6 apr 2013". A downside is that the abbreviations for the month are locale dependent.
- Stick to the international standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601); YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.

If you are getting dates from user input it is impossible to distingiush between MM-DD and DD-MM in all cases. But there are some things that can help. A number >12 is obsiously a day, not a month. If you know that the user is from Europe, the date will probably be DD-MM-YYYY. A person from the USA is more likely to use MM-DD-YYYY.